# yii2 2amigos datapicker. Can't save to model

Tags: datepicker, yii2, widget

I have start_date and end_date columns in my model.

In the form I put:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(
DatePicker::className(), [
     'inline' => false, 
    'template' => '<div class="well well-sm" style="background-color: #fff; width:250px">{input}</div>',
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'dd-M-yyyy'
    ]
]);?>
```

It's saving null parameters in start_date and end_date columns.
P.S. Bth, how to hide a calendar? I want to make it hidden, and when I click on input it will be automatically shown to choose date.

Comment: If u print the post value then is it showing values of start_date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?= $form->field($model, 'start_date')->widget(
     DatePicker::className(), [
      'inline' => false, 
     // remove the template
    'clientOptions' => [
        'autoclose' => true,
        'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd' //change the date format
    ]
    ]);?>
```

The calender remained open because of the template. Use `yyyy-mm-dd` date format to save the date

Comment: If it worked for you, then you can accept the answer ;)